# How to configure the required authentication for the chat room

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the post comment system in android, I want to create a chat option upon clicking the button only among the post author and comment author only, if anyone else clicks it should not open the chat room.

I am using the below code for the same purpose, but it is not working the way required. you can refer the idea of chat system in stackoverflow, the similar thing I want. the below code is in adapter class linking to the button on the recyclerview item. I am the PostAuthorId and CommentAuthorId are already confirmed, I have to just set the condition if the login user is the same as one of them.

i am using firestore database for the same

if any more information is required do let me know.

```
                commentsViewHolder.chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 //   @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if(PostAuthorID == mAuth.getUid() || CommentAuthorId == mAuth.getUid())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CommentActivity.this, ChatRoomActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(ChatRoomActivity.CHAT_ROOM_ID, ChatRoomId);
                            intent.putExtra(ChatRoomActivity.CHAT_ROOM_NAME, ChatRoomName);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "You are not authenticated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error because of this code?

Comment: Also, elaborate more on how and what are you storing in PostAuthorID and CommentAuthorID

Comment: not particular error, but it's not working , I want the on onclick event to happen on true conditions, and even upon the true conditions it is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is that `==` won't work for strings.
Use `PostAuthorID.equals(mAuth.getUid())` to compare strings, not the `==` operator. *`mAuth.getUid()` returns a String and I am assuming that `PostAuthorID` is a String too*

Like:

```
if(PostAuthorID.equals(mAuth.getUid()) || CommentAuthorId.equals(mAuth.getUid())){
....
} else {
....
}
```

> **Remember:**
>
> `==` operator only compares object references, while the `String.equals()` method compares both String's values!